# imgAreaSelect + changing aspectRatio on the fly

Tags: jquery

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now. I couldn't find any answer/solution so far and I hope one of you can help me out.

Situation is like this: I'm using imgAreaSelect to crop an image. But the user has the possibility to change the aspect ratio. This by entering a width and a height (100:20 for example).

You can find my code below:

```
var ias = jQuery('#photo').imgAreaSelect({instance:true});
ias.setOptions({aspectRatio:'100:20'});
ias.update();
```

So I have my instance of the imgAreaSelect in the var `ias`. But somehow I cannot change the settings through `SetOptions()`.
The error I am getting is the following:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getOwnPropertyNames'`

But the strange this is, if I do `console.dir(ias)` I  perfectly see my object in the console. Everything else works as it should. Cropping works perfectly, I just cannot edit my options through `setOptions()`.

Am I forgetting something?

Thanks in advance! Steve

Answer (score 0):

set `setOptions` to `true`. See example code:

```
var own = $('#crop_img').imgAreaSelect({x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: $('#crop_img').width(), y2: $('#crop_img').height(),
    handles: true, instance:true, 
    aspectRatio:"{{ $javascript->ratio }}",
    resizable:true,
    persistent:true,
    **setOptions:true**,
    imageWidth:"{{ $javascript->width }}",
    imageHeight:"{{ $javascript->height }}",
```

Comment: Could you please format the code and also add some explanation why this would work?

Comment: I found out by just trying and debugging the onInit function.    onInit: function (img, selection) {
  $('#ratio_id').on('change', function() {
   ratio = this.value;
   own.setOptions({aspectRatio:ratio});
   own.update();
  });
 },